# Generalized eigenspace with a parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm working on a problem about generalized eigenspaces with a specific parameter but I got stuck and would appreciate help.

> Let $A \in \mathbb{R^{2\times2}}$, we define the generalized eigenspace as $H_{\lambda}=\{v\in V: (A-\lambda I_n)^r(v)=0 \}$.
>
> Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}
> 0 & t\\
> -1 & 0
> \end{pmatrix}.$ Determine the generalized eigenspace of $A$ in terms of $t$ and state whether A is diagonalizable.

What I have so far:
$$ p_A(x)=\det(xI_n-A)=x^2+t \implies \lambda_1= \sqrt{-t},\ \lambda_2=-\sqrt{-t}$$
To make sure we end up with real eigenvalues we restrict $t$ such that $t<0$, then:
$$A-\lambda_1I_n= \begin{pmatrix}
-\sqrt{-t} & t \\
-1 & -\sqrt{-t} 
\end{pmatrix}, A-\lambda_2I_n=\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{-t} & t \\
-1 & \sqrt{-t}
\end{pmatrix}$$
From here I managed to use the rank-nullity theorem to state that $A$ is diagonalizable but I don't know how I can express the generalized eigenspace in terms of $t$ especially when its already difficulty to find the eigenvectors by themselves:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
-\sqrt{-t}& t \\
-1 & -\sqrt{-t} 
\end{pmatrix}v=(\sqrt{-t})v \implies 
\begin{pmatrix}
(-\sqrt{-t})v_1+tv_2\\
-v_1-(\sqrt{-t})v_2
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
(\sqrt{-t})v_1 \\
(\sqrt{-t})v_2
\end{pmatrix}$$
This is about as far as I got.

Comment: $t=0$ also has a real square root. Also what is $r$ in the definition of $H_\lambda$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First split into cases based on the sign of $t$. If $t < 0$, then $\det(A - \lambda I_2)\ne 0$ for all $\lambda\in \mathbb R$, so all $H_\lambda = \{0\}$.

If $t = 0$, then $\det(A - \lambda I_2) = 0$ when $\lambda = 0$. Additionally, since $A^2 = 0$, that means all vectors are in $H_0$. In this case, $H_0 = \mathbb R^2$ and all others are $\{0\}$.

If $t > 0$, we have $\det(A - \lambda I_2) = 0$ for $t = \pm\sqrt{-t}$, as you found. You can actually calculate the powers directly as $(A\pm \sqrt{-t}I_2)^r = (-2\sqrt{t})^{r-1}(A\pm\sqrt{-t}I_2)$, so the generalized eigenspace will be the same as the regular one for these. So you'll have $H_{\pm\sqrt{-t}} = \{w: w = c v_{\pm \sqrt{-t}}, c\in \mathbb R\}$, where $v_{\pm\sqrt{-t}}$ are the eigenvectors corresponding to those eigenvalues. All other $H_\lambda$ are again $\{0\}$.

To find the eigenvectors, you're on the right track, but you've written $(A - \lambda I_2) v = \lambda v$, rather than the correct $(A - \lambda I_2)v = 0$. Fix this and you'll find $v_{\sqrt{-t}} = (-\sqrt{t}, 1)$. Then repeat for $\lambda = -\sqrt{-t}$